# mysql always using maximum connection

Tags: mysql, lamp, slow-connection

I have LAMP server having 4 core CPU and 32 GB RAM.We are running a large website on it. I have following issues now in my server.

1. When I use [Mysqlreport](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport) tool to monitor the mysql server i am always seeing the connection usage as below. And the users reporting connection issues in the website.

_

> Connections _________________________________________________________
>
> Max used          251 of  250      %Max: 100.40 Total         748.71k 
>   3.5/s

But when I use "show process list" command it will output nothing. We are using MyISAM engine for all our DBs.

My Mysql Config File is pasted below:

> ######################
>
> [mysqld]
>
> max_connections = 250
>
> set-variable=local-infile=0
>
> datadir=/var/lib/mysql
>
> socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
>
> user=mysql
>
> skip-name-resolve
>
> skip-bdb
>
> wait_timeout = 60
>
> thread_cache_size = 100
>
> table_cache = 1024
>
> key_buffer = 384M
>
> log_slow_queries=/mysql-log/mysql-slow.log
>
> query-cache-size=512M
>
> query-cache-type=1
>
> query_cache_limit=20M
>
> [mysqld_safe]
>
> log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
>
> pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
>
> #

Who is using my Mysql connection pool? How can I find it?

And i have another issue.

2. Sometimes the Load average goes beyond 4-8 range. See below:

> 13:40:02 up 2 days, 10:39,  0 users,  load average: 5.03, 1.68, 0.93

At that time i can see mysql is the top consumer of the CPU. Is there any optimization needed in mysql Server?

Comment: `"show process list" command it will output nothing` - what's "nothing"? Could you post the exact output?

Comment: Try `show processlist` instead of `show process list`

Comment: Anything showing in netstat, could be that you have open connections that are not being closed by your applications?

Answer (score 1):

> But when I use "show process list" command it will output nothing

The there's something broken on your system. It should at least show the connection running processlist. It will also show current idle connections.

> Max used 251 of 250 %Max: 100.40 Total 748.71k 3.5/s

Sounds like this is reporting [max_used_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_used_connections) which is the high water mark since the server was last restarted - which is not the same as the [current number of connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections).

> Is there any optimization needed in mysql Server?

Impossible to say from the information provided. Although since you've not provided a lot of the relevant information for making such a determination then the answer is probably yes.

Try running mysqltuner.pl against the instance. Also read some of the many answers here on tuning a LAMP instance.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable replies. It was my interpretation mistake of mysqlreport documentation.Thank you symcbean for pointing out this. S